qsub -pe mpi doesn't want to run
I created a file with molecule coordinates that I wanted to optimize, but when i end the file with esc :wq, and execute the command qsub -pe mpi 8 [name of file], I only get errors.
my file
What am I doing wrong?
(I am a beginner)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
